# Name for the surface formed by taking a filled in square and identifying diagonal vertices?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, surfaces, quotient-spaces, visualization

Consider the surface formed by taking a filled in square and identifying diagonal vertices. For example, $(0,0)\sim(1,1)$ and $(0,1)\sim(1,0).$

Image courtesy of @robjohn:

[image]

> Is there a name for this particular surface? What can be said about the curvature?

Parametrization:

$$\scriptsize\left\{(x+y)\cos\left(\tfrac\pi4(x+y)\right)+(x-y)\cos\left(\tfrac\pi4(x-y)\right),(x+y)\cos\left(\tfrac\pi4(x+y)\right)-(x-y)\cos\left(\tfrac\pi4(x-y)\right),\tfrac\pi2\sin\left(\tfrac\pi2xy\right)\right\}$$

$x,y\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: Here's an [interactive plot](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxlUMFugzAMvfMVvjWhgQ6206RIO-08acdpqkJwWjQgKA4a_P0MrExTc3CUvOf3nu2C74DMBfOh9XEtj3U-mGA6jKGxZxqDMxah6QYfIrztyPsGJDU6cGJSMMvnBPgY0CAmOPIHpGA9ib_X0MAJnuTKqzZe9o-X3fMCxjH0LHuESvGVLRc1PbNTmG_kcm8rkzWTvYXaBSoSUzrLJHlp-ojB2LgSz8ItM-lX0xKycsRBF6fyQbG77cygCVu00QdBvAGshfWtDwyQgi-cNcWQW0PofFtLBSxpxjbqg7do-oP83UrV1zwvBdNfUGSFgmKz2makq_8Wd7sVToHgRrV0S7UyOdNir4VlcE_ysQT9lGy_zbJW-QOKO4-j&lang=sage) using SageMathCell. The `cf` coloring function should return a value in [0, 1].

Comment: @PM2Ring does that show the curvature? green=negative, blue=positive?

Comment: Not really. That color function is just`abs(x*y)`, but you can edit it into anything you like that returns a value in the range [0, 1] for x & y in the range [-1, 1]. Then the colormap converts that value to a color. You can see a gallery of the colormaps here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a name for this particular surface.

About the curvature, we can say that the surface, call it $S,$ has positive, negative, and zero curvature. This is due to a theorem which says:

Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^ 3$ be a connected, regular, compact, orientable surface which is not homeomorphic to a sphere. Then $S$ has positive, negative and zero curvature.

To illustrate this, the Gaussian curvature is represented on the surface $S$ below.

Red=Negative, Green=Zero, and Blue=Positive.

[image]

Image courtesy of @robjohn.

Comment: The curve where the Gaussian curvature is zero lies on a particular hue of green, but not all the greenish area has curvature $0$. The curvature is a continuum and varies with the hue.